# Adding Api interface in ViewModel constructor and navigation stops working Prism

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I'm using VS 17 for Xamarin Forms. I've set up Prism in my Xamarin.Forms app and I just added a reference to my Api interface (in ViewModel Constructor) and it makes the app stop navigation to the second page. I need to do this in order to pass parameters etc. I followed this guide:

https://blog.qmatteoq.com/prism-for-xamarin-forms-basic-navigation-and-dependency-injection-part-2/

This is what I did to make the navigation stop working:

```
private readonly IService _Service;
private ObservableCollection<TodoItem> _topSeries;

public ObservableCollection<TodoItem> TopSeries
{
    get { return _topSeries; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _topSeries, value); }
}
```

This is the constructor:

```
public SecondPageViewModel(IService Service, INavigationService navigationService)   
{
    _Service = Service;
    _navigationService = navigationService;
}
```

So I cant even reach the above viewmodel because of the above code that I added. I tried to put break points on the DelegateCommand (on first ViewModel) but it just stops after InitializeComponent(); and then nothing happens. No error messages! Thanks!

Update:

My Service class that fetches data:

```
public class Service : IService
{

    public List<TodoItem> TodoList { get; private set; }
    HttpClient client;

    Service()
    {
        client = new HttpClient();
        client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000;
    }

    public async Task<List<TodoItem>> DataAsync()
    {

        TodoList = new List<TodoItem>();

        var uri = new Uri(string.Format(Constants.RestUrl, string.Empty));

        try
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                TodoList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TodoItem>>(content);
                Debug.WriteLine(content);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(@"ERROR {0}", ex.Message);
        }

        return TodoList;
    }
}
```

This is my App.Xaml.cs

```
protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
    containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<NavigationPage>();
    containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<View.MainPage, MainPageViewModel>();
    containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<View.SecondPage, SecondPageViewModel>();
    containerRegistry.Register<IService, Service>();
}
```

My Interface:

```
public interface IService
{
    Task<List<TodoItem>> DataAsync();
}
```

This is how I navigate (click from listview):

```
private EventItem _selectedEvent { get; set; }
public EventItem SelectedEvent
{
    get { return _selectedEvent; }  
    set
    {
        if (_selectedEvent != value)
        {
            if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
            {
                _selectedEvent = null;
            }
            else
            {
                _selectedEvent = value;
            }
            NavigationParameters navParams = new NavigationParameters();
            navParams.Add("PassedValue", _todoItem.name);

            _navigationService.NavigateAsync("SecondPage", navParams);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

When I debug without the ApiService code the command is taking me to new new constructor in the new viewmodel. With the code it does not reach the contructor.

Comment: The part where you state `This is what I did to make the navigation stop working` is confusing to me, how does that stop the navigation?

Comment: Well, If I remove the above code the navigation works. It all of a sudden stopped working just because of adding that code. @EpicKip

Comment: The reason it stops working is not clear from that code (where it originates exactly idk). Could you try to make a test project and re-create the issue with as little code as possible? Then people could more easily help and identify the issue :)

Comment: I have another post here where I show my code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53520601/pass-data-parameter-from-model-to-next-page-prism-xamarin-forms?noredirect=1#comment93966447_53520601 @EpicKip

Comment: Here is the HTTPClient code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53542609/cant-register-data-services-prism-xamarin-forms/53542759#53542759 @EpicKip

Comment: Could you edit that in here? This question has to be clear on its own not with links or comments so it will be useful for future readers.

Comment: @EpicKip Edited.

Comment: Your issue is most likely not related with the code you provided. The code you provided looks good.

Comment: Ok, Im thinking it has to do with the registration of the Service. Do I have to include the Service in all of the viewmodels (constructor)? @WojciechKulik

Comment: No, backup  your code. Try to remove all not related things, like bindings etc. Leave only services registration, empty viewmodels with constructors and check then if issue still occurs.

Comment: When I remove the Service from the constructor the navigation works. I dont understand how that can block the navigation. @WojciechKulik

Comment: Adding Service to all viewmodels (constructor) = app crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your code you have declared constructor like this:

```
Service()
{
    // ...
}
```

You didn't set access modifier, therefore the default one is `internal`. Here is the definition:

> Internal types or members are accessible only within files in the same
>   assembly.

Most likely you have your `Service.cs` declared in another Assembly and Prism can't access its constructor. 
Your navigation doesn't work because dependency injection fails. To fix it, just change your access modifier to `public`:

```
public Service()
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: You're welcome :). Strange that Prism doesn't throw exception in this case neither initializes ViewModel with empty service.